# shared_ptr chain/branch with a second deleter

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a situation where I need to know when the user of a shared_ptr is done, that is, when the user has finally released all copies of it.  Normally one just uses a deleter here, but there is a small catch in this case. The underlying object is already a shared_ptr!

That is, in pseudo-code:

```
shared_ptr<T> a( new T );
.
.
.
shared_ptr<T> b( a, bind( delete_func, id ) );
```

I'm spawning a new branch of sorts from the original shared_ptr. This new shared_ptr `b` may be copied and used like a normal shared_ptr but the delete_func must be called when this particular branch is done.  Now, I can't just use `a.get()` here either since this new shared_ptr must retain the underlying object as well (it may be the last shared_ptr for it).

I'm looking for some way to do this without having to drastically change the framework. Does anybody see a good simple solution?

*I'm using the boost library for smart pointers and bind.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one possible solution.

Create a deleter function like this:

```
void delete_func( int id, shared_ptr<T> underlying );
```

Then to chain the shared_ptr do this:

```
shared_ptr<T> b( a.get(), bind( &delete_func, id, a ) );
```

This creates a new unattached shared_ptr with a custom deleter (my branch). One of the parameters is the original shared_ptr, thus this should maintain the underlying shared_ptr object as well. Now I just need to test this a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't this call the deleter when the last copy of `b` goes out of scope. Copies of `a` may well be in scope at the time. - Why not just add a custom deleter to `a` when it is created in the first place?

Comment: @visitor, that is exactly what is desired.  Essentially `b` is supposed to have its own lifetime, which when it ends unregisters itself via a deleter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want to have the two separate layers of `shared_ptr`, why not just provide the appropriate deleter that will notify you and then call `checked_deleter` on the pointer? That way you only need a single deleter and you are back at the simple problem of providing *one* deleter to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Consider that `a` is part of some internal module. A function is called and needs access to `a` as well, but the system has to know when this external caller is done using it. Thus it can't return `a` directly since it would never know then, so in some way it must hook into the lifetime of this new copy of the variable.